# quarkus-smallrye-openapi - Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus

I have one rest endpoint which uses one class as the openapi schema:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses.APIResponse;

@Path("/orders")
@RequestScoped
public class OrdersRest {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Create a new order", content = {
                        @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = OrderDto.class)) })
        public Response create(OrderDto request) throws SessionNotFound {
```

The OrderDto class has one attribute that refers to another class, that exists on my project:

```java
public class SessionDto {
    private SessionSettingsProperties[] sessionSettingsProperties;
```

When I access the swagger-ui, I am receiving the error:

```
Errors
 
Resolver error at paths./session.get.responses.200.content.application/json.schema.properties.sessionSettingsProperties.items.$ref

Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/SessionSettingsProperties does not exist in document
```

[image]

I'm using the Quarkus 1.13.1.Final version.

I've found this [issue in Quarkus project](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14814) that looks similar, but I believe is not exactly the same problem I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem including one org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema annotation in my field of the SessionDto class like this:

```java
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;

public class SessionDto {

    @Schema(implementation = SessionSettingsProperties[].class)
    private SessionSettingsProperties[] sessionSettingsProperties;
```

Comment: Looks like smallrye-openapi weren't scanning arrays properly, I've opened this issue https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/issues/779 and they make a PR to fix this. I guess the next Quarkus version after 1.13.2.Final will have this.